# Dynamic Value in Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

How to pass dynamic value in Retrofit? I am able to retrieve if its a static variable and not with dynamic variable.

```
https://www.dfdf.com/get_sports_name.php?menu=?Soccer

    Now:
    interface SportsName
    {
     @GET("get_sports_name.php?menu=Soccer")
     fun getSports() : Observable<SportsResponse>
    }
    Expectation:
    interface SportsName
    {
     @GET("get_sports_name.php?menu=$sportsname")
     fun getSports() : Observable<SportsResponse>
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `@Query` annotation to the method parameter and remove `?menu=$sportsname` from your path:

```
interface SportsName{
    @GET("get_sports_name.php")
    fun getSports(@Query("menu") menu: String) : Observable<SportsResponse>
}
```

Then you can call this method so:

```
yourApiInterface.getSports("Your value")
```

Comment: thanks for your response. My quesion here is where to pass the menu value now like icehockey, soccer, football....

Comment: Here I am getting Error like no value passed for menu.            val apiSports = retrofit.create(ApiSports::class.java)
            apiSports.getSports()

Comment: Just call `getSports` method with necessary value. For example `getSports("soccer")` or `getSports("icehockey")`

Comment: Done. You are awesome :)